# Cómo obtener los digitos separados de una matriz unidimensional proveniente de una bidimensional en Java

Tags: java, matriz

Quiero poder acceder a cada número por separado de la matriz m pero me los lanza con el lugar en memoria que posee porque quiero crear una sola matriz unidimensional con cada número, si me pueden ayudar gracias de antemano!!!

```
public static void CrearMatriz(int []m){
    
   String num = String.valueOf(m);
   char[] digitos = num.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digitos));
    }
   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
   int[][] b = new int[4][4];
    b[0][1] = 2;    b[0][3] = 6;
    b[1][3] = 8;    b[1][0] = 1;
    b[2][2] = 9;    b[2][3] = 4;
    b[3][0] = 7;    b[3][1] = 5;
    

  
      for (int f = 0; f <b.length; f++) {
        CrearMatriz(b[f]);
          System.out.println(" ");
          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer tal que así, el código está comentado. La función `flatMatrix()` recibirá un array bidimensional de enteros y devolverá un nuevo array unidimensional con todos los elementos del array bidimensional original

```
public class Main {

  public static Integer[] flatMatrix(Integer[][] matrix){
    // el array unidimensional tendra el tamaño de la primera dimension de la matriz multiplicada la segunda dimension de la misma
    Integer[] flatted = new Integer[matrix.length * matrix[0].length];
    Integer pointer = 0; // apuntador
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) // doble bucle para iterar por la matriz, puedo quitar las llaves en este for
      for(int h = 0; h < matrix[0].length; h++){
        flatted[pointer] = matrix[i][h]; // usamos el apuntador para asignar a dicha posicion del array el valor de la matriz en la posicion i,h
        pointer++; // incrementamos apuntador
      }
    return flatted; // retornamos
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[][]{{1,26,37,4}, {51,-6,7,28}, {98,10,115,12}, {913,14,135,16}}; // podemos definir una matriz de esta forma, tendra un tamaño de 4x4

    // creamos el array unidimensional con el array devuelto por flatMatrix(), podemos pasar matrices de cualquier dimension y obtendremos el array correspondiente siempre que sea de tipo Integer[][]
    Integer[] flatted = flatMatrix(matrix); 

    System.out.print(" - ");
    for(int i = 0; i < flatted.length; i++) System.out.print(flatted[i] + " - "); // imprimiendo array resultante
    
  }
}
```

Cualquier duda solo pregunta.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

con un par de correcciones, en tus métodos, tenemos todo funcionando.

```
public static void CrearMatriz( int[] m, int linea, int sale[] ) { 
   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      System.out.print(  m[ i ] );
      sale[ i + linea ] = m[ i ];
   }
}

public static void maintenance() {
   int[][] b = new int[ 4 ][ 4 ];
   b[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 2;
   b[ 0 ][ 3 ] = 6;
   b[ 1 ][ 3 ] = 8;
   b[ 1 ][ 0 ] = 1;
   b[ 2 ][ 2 ] = 9;
   b[ 2 ][ 3 ] = 4;
   b[ 3 ][ 0 ] = 7;
   b[ 3 ][ 1 ] = 5;

   int salida[] = new int[ 16 ];

   for( int f = 0; f < b.length; f++ ) {
      CrearMatriz( b[ f ], f * 4, salida );
      System.out.println( " " );
   }
}
```

Como verás, ahora **CrearMatriz** recibe varios argumentos:

1. el sub-array a imprimir
2. un número que nos indica cuantas posiciones debemos adelantar con cada nuevo sub-array.
3. el array de salida.

Modificaciones:

- primero quité **String num = String.valueOf(m);**, ya que **m** es un array, por lo que **valueOf( m )** no te devolverá lo que esperas.
- También eliminé **char[] digitos = num.toCharArray();**, que no se sabe bien que hacia ahí.
- Dentro del for reemplacé **System.out.println( Arrays.toString( digitos ));** por **System.out.print( m[ i ] );** que imprime el valor de los contenidos del array que recibe el método.
- Agregué la linea **sale[ i + linea ] = m[ i ];**, para crear un único array con todos los valores,

En el main:

- agregué **int salida[] = new int[ 16 ];** que crea el array que se usará como salida.
- modifiqué la llamada a **CrearMatriz( b[ f ], f * 4, salida );**, de está manera le paso:

  - el sub-array que se está recorriendo.
  - el desplazamiento del array de salida en función de el sub-array recorrido.
  - el array de salida.

Eso es todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo logré entender!!